# Paperclip without a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have paperclip (with S3) working in my application, for audio files. The model definition connects S3 with paperclip.

```
# attachments
has_attached_file :audio, storage: :s3, s3_credentials: Proc.new{|a| a.instance.s3_credentials}
validates_attachment_content_type :audio, :content_type => [ 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg3', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/x-mpg', 'audio/x-mpegaudio' ]
```

I can upload the files via a rails simple_form, using this code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@sentence) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  .
  <%= f.input :audio, as: :file %>
  .   
<% end %>
```

I would also like to create audio using a background (Resque) process. This code retrieves an audio stream from a web API and attempts to save it to the existing model instance. It does not work.

```
sentences.each do |sentence|
   sentence.audio = get_audio(sentence.sentence)
   sentence.save
end
```

Paperclip doesn't seem to know how to handle the audio stream.

```
 failed: #<Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError: No handler found for "\xFF\xF3\xC8\xC4\x00\x00\x00\x03H\x00\x00\x00\x00LAME3.99.5\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0
```

** PROGRESS **

I made some progress: wrote the audio stream to an Tempfile... but now Paperclip is complaining about encoding

```
 def get_audio_tempfile(target)
   audio = translator.speak "#{target}", :language => "#{@language_cd}", :format => 'audio/mp3', :options => 'MaxQuality'
   tempfile = Tempfile.new("target_temp.mp3")
   tempfile.binmode
   tempfile.write(audio)
   tempfile.close
   tempfile.open
   tempfile
 end
```

Error:

```
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename target_temp.mp320160226-32064- r391y9 (audio/mpeg from Headers, [] from Extension), content type  discovered from file command: audio/mpeg. See documentation to allow this combination.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get what exactly your get_audio method is doing, but you need to make sure it returns a file handle, e.g.

```
sentence.audio = File.new(path_to_your_file, "r")
sentence.save
```

As for your Tempfile approach, make sure to create it like this

```
Tempfile.new([ 'foobar', '.mp3' ])
```

This way PaperClip won't complain about the file extension

Answer (score 0):

A summary of how to save an audio stream to Paperclip / S3 without going via the view.

Assuming Paperclip is working and writing to S3, the following steps are needed to upload a file (using Paperclip) from somewhere else than the view (in my case, it is a Resque process).

Why do this: to allow for a fix of foreground and background processing, or to batch upload a lot of data.

**model**

```
  # attachments
  has_attached_file :audio, storage: :s3, s3_credentials: Proc.new{|a| a.instance.s3_credentials}
  validates_attachment_content_type :audio, :content_type => [ 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg3', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/x-mpg', 'audio/x-mpegaudio' ]
```

**view**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@sentence) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  .
  <%= f.input :audio, as: :file %>
  .   
<% end %>
```

**job**

```
 sentence.audio = get_audio_tempfile(sentence.sentence)
 sentence.save
```

**get_audio_tempfile**

```
def get_audio_tempfile(target)
  audio = translator.speak "#{target}", :language => "#{@language_cd}", :format => 'audio/mp3', :options => 'MaxQuality'
  tempfile = Tempfile.new(['target_temp','.mp3'])
  tempfile.binmode
  tempfile.write(audio)
  tempfile.rewind
  tempfile
end
```

Important notes:

- include the correct filename extension
- rewind the tempfile
- don't close the tempfile before using it

Thank you to @tobmatth for the help with the file issues.